# Using keyword LIMIT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("data_wis1") or die(mysql_error());
  if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM info WHERE ID = '".$id."'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  }
  if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
  }
  else {
    $page = 1;
  }
$start_from = ($page-1) * 1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info LIMIT 0, 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
  <table>
    <?php
      for($i = 0; $i <mysql_num_rows($query); $i++) {
        $id = mysql_result($query, $i, "ID");
    $caseStatus = mysql_result($query, $i, "Case_Status");

    echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$caseStatus."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href='del.php?id=".$id."'><input type='button' value='Delete'></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
      }
      ?>
  </table>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM info";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $total_records = $row[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 1);

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
      echo "<a href='del.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
    }
  ?>
</html>
```

My problem is that whenever i click page 2,3,4... the display doesn't change. Page 2,3,4 gets the display of page 1. It should be like this. For example, page 1 should display ID = 1 and case status = open. Page 2 should display ID = 2 and case status = close and so on.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: LIMIT accepts one or two parameters, in your case the first is the offset, the second one is how many items you want to retrieve.
you're not using your `$start_from` variable, try something like this: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM info LIMIT $start_from, 1";`

Comment: @TrevorDonahue oh i didn't see that. thank you so much. :)

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @tereško oh i see. i'll go check your links then. thanks.

Comment: If you decide to pick PDO, then [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a good basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never used $start_from in anywhere. I think `$sql = "SELECT * FROM info LIMIT '".$start_from."', 1";` is the answer